# Redshift Spectrum not reading nested data in Parquet format

Tags: json, amazon-redshift, parquet

I have a table in Redshift that looks like this (much simplified):

```
TABLE events 
(uuid CHAR(36),
event_name VARCHAR(256),
payload SUPER,
created_at timestamp
);
```

The payload column is always a JSON object and it works just fine natively in Redshift, I can access the fields with dot notation, etc.

I want to UNLOAD a subset of rows of this table to S3 in Parquet format and query it through Redshift Spectrum.

So I do the UNLOAD operation as follows:

```
UNLOAD ('SELECT * FROM events') 
TO 's3://my-bucket/spectrum/events'
iam_role 'my_iam_role'
PARQUET
PARTITION BY (event_name VARCHAR)
MANIFEST VERBOSE;
```

The unloading completes successfully.

Then I create an external table in an external schema (using the default Glue Data Catalog):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE spectrum_db.events(
uuid CHAR(36),
created_at TIMESTAMP,
payload STRUCT <
app: STRUCT <
name: VARCHAR(256),
platform: VARCHAR(256)
>
>
)
PARTITIONED BY (event_name VARCHAR)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/spectrum/events/manifest';

ALTER TABLE spectrum_db.events
ADD PARTITION (event_name='apps')
LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/spectrum/events/event_name=apps/';
```

Then I query:

```
SELECT uuid, 
       created_at, 
       payload.app.name, 
       payload.app.platform 
FROM spectrum_db.events
LIMIT 100
```

It successfully returns uuid and created_at, however the nested columns are always null while there is actually data on S3 in the payload column. For example if I run

```
SET json_serialization_enable TO TRUE;
```

I see the raw payload in the payload column with a simple `SELECT *` query from the same external table.

Additionally, if I UNLOAD in JSON format, the same external table defintion works perfectly fine and I can access the payload elements.

Do you have any idea if I am missing anything in the UNLOAD or external table schema creation process? I suspect maybe this could be fixed by setting some TABLE PROPERTIES specific to Parquet. But I fail to find even any documentation on those.